# The Application Emacs is Not Open Anymore (macOS High Sierra)

Tags: osx, debugging

I am using Emacs (25.2.1) on macOS High Sierra 10.13.2, and when trying to open a simple .txt file using Emacs as the editor, I get the error "The application Emacs is not open anymore".

**Details:** This error happens when Emacs is already open, and I try to open a file with it via double-clicking in Finder. Somehow, it does not happen when Emacs is closed and I open a file with it via double-clicking in Finder. After the first file is open, double-clicking does not work anymore (I get the error mentioned above), and the only way to open a file with Emacs is via C-x C-f.

**Question:** How can I fix the problem so that I can double-click in finder to have a file be opened with Emacs?

Comment: Do you see the same thing when you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: I started Emacs using `/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs -Q &` on terminal (for some reason just `emacs -Q` or `emacs -Q &` would not open the GUI), and then loading the text files worked. I guess it is time to bisect.

Comment: I also have this issue, but on Mojave.

Comment: The issue mysteriously went away for me, then came back; no idea why. It happens now on Catalina.

Comment: @Drew It's definitely not an issue with init files; it seems to have something to do the launchservices database, maybe?

Comment: I now have one mac which reliably demonstrates this issue and another mac which reliably doesn't. I don't know what the difference in configuration is.